# C++ Time manipulation functions

Tags: c++, time

Here is what I am struggling with.

I have to determine whether current time, `time_t`, is overlapping with a triplet of 
day of week (0 Sunday to 6 Saturday)

```
start time = minutes from midnight 
end time = minutes from midnight
```

So 1/17/2012 13:00:00 does overlap with 2(tuesday) 600, 900
   1/17/2012 13:00:00 does not overlap with 1(monday) 0, 1000

Any thoughts on how to implement this?

Thanks
Reza

Comment: strftime and converting the time_t to struct tm...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert your `time_t` to a `struct tm` using `localtime_r` (or `localtime_s` on Windows).  Then you will have day of the week (in `tm_wday`) and the various other values you can compare against.